# How to Suppress Header

Tags: crystal-reports, header, footer, subreport

I am working with Crystal Report, I have data which is grouped. Below I am attaching the designer view of the report.

The issue is: my header repeats on every page, if my Sub report goes to second or third page, or as long as it grows..

How should I suppress my header if the detail portion of the report only occupying the first page ..?

[image]

Comment: have you tried `pagenumber`?

Comment: no , I dont know about it, can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

in page header ``supress`

```
if pagenumber=1
then true
else false
```

Comment: but when my main report extends up to multiple pages in that case I have to retain headers for those pages as well.

Comment: when extends to multiple pages then page number won't be `2` then header will be visible

Comment: what I want is that, On my Sub report which will be on page three wont be showing the Headers of First report.

Answer (score 0):

In your group expert >> Click on "Options">> Select "Options" tab >> uncheck repeat group header on each page.